# Change the attribute of a given element without knowing its full id with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `foreach` statement that generates some table lines and on each table line there is a `variant` with a unique id.

I want to have a button near that `variant` that changes an attribute of a form from `hidden` to `visible`, but I want to change only on that line.

```
@foreach($variants as $variant)
<tr>
{{$variant->name}}

<button id="show{{$variant->id}}>Show Form</button>

<form action="POST" hidden="true" id="variantForm{{$variant->id}}>
<input type="text" name="someInput"/>
<button type="submit/>
</form>

</tr>
@endforeach
```

And in the jQuery I wannt something like

```
<script>

$(".show[id_from_foreach]").click(
function(){ change to visible only the form with id=variantForm[id_from_foreach] });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1. <button class="show_variant">Show Form</button>
2. <script>
    $(".show_variant").click(function() {
        var $btn = $(this);
        var $form = $btn.next();
        $form.show();
    });
</script>
```

or if you want to set id you can do something like this:

```
1. <button class="show_variant" data-variant-id="{{ $variant->id }}">ShowForm</button>
2.   <script>
        $(".show_variant").click(function() {
            var $btn = $(this);
            var variantId = $btn.data('variantId');
            var $form = $('#variantForm' + variantId);
            $form.show();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Just FYI there's no such thing as a `hidden` attribute in a HTML form.

Comment: I like the second solution better, since it doesn't constrain you to a specific DOM structure.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var variantId = $btn.data('variant-id');` because above you wrote `<button class="show_variant" data-variant-id=" .. >` ?

Comment: No. Data attributes in jquery can be reached in camelCase

Answer (score 0):

This is a prime example of where incremental/generated id attributes are an anti-pattern. Don't use them.

Instead use a common class on the elements in your HTML, then traverse the DOM in your JS to find related elements which should be amended. Try this:

```html
@foreach($variants as $variant)
  <tr>
    {{$variant->name}}

    <button class="show-button" id="show{{$variant->id}}>Show Form</button>

    <form action="POST" hidden="true" id="variantForm{{$variant->id}}>
      <input type="text" name="someInput" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

```js
$(".show-button").click(function(){ 
  $(this).next('form').show();
});
```